# Cassandra: Is it normal to have so many gc.log processes

Tags: logging, cassandra, garbage-collection, htop, multiple-processes

I am quite new to cassandra, so if someone can explain me what I see here. I have a cassandra ring with 16 nodes(simple strategy) and if I use htop on the nodes I see too many gc.log processes taking place which also I think occupy a lot of memory! 16 of them belong to the 16 nodes, but what about the rest? Is that normal to have so many logging events?

[image: cassandraprocesses]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `gc.log` processes, it's the single Cassandra process that has an option that specifies where to store `gc.log` file.  You see so many because by default `htop` shows all threads of the process, not single process item (see [this answer for explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10403/271685)).  You can check this by executing `ps -aef|grep gc.log` - you should see only one item for Cassandra process.